# Mass of Isotope

Tags: nuclear-physics, isotopes, mass-spectrometry

I am designing a simple Mass Spectrometer.

I need to find radius of $Pb_{204}^{-}$ when deflecting. I have this equation:

> [image: equation]

I know everything in that equation except the *mass*. I have

> [image: this]

How can I find the mass for the equation?

Comment: It is shown in the last column "Isotope mass"

https://wwwndc.jaea.go.jp/cgi-bin/nuclinfo2014?82%2C204

Answer (score 0):

The mass of a neutral $Pb_{204}$ atom is given right in your green image.

Because you have a negative $Pb_{204}^-$ ion,
you need to add the mass of one electron.

Comment: @jmh I don't see how the radius of the nucleus is relevant here.
The radius $R$ in the asked question is the radius of the curved ion beam
when flying through the magnetic field in the
[mass spectrometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_spectrometry#Parts_of_a_mass_spectrometer),
typically a few inches.

Comment: you are right. my bad. Thank you!